# how can I toggle submenu separately on my navbar using vue js composition API

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm working on this navbar using vue.js composition API, and now I'm trying to toggle the submenus when I click on it. Since I'm iterating an object to show the submenus I cannot add the "click" event on each one of them, so my question is how can I accomplish this, is it possible?.

this is my code so far (I added a variable (showSubmenu) and I bind it to the "ul" to toggle using the "v-if" but this caused all the submenus to show at once)

```
<!-- ====================SCRIPTS =================== -->
<script setup>
import Icon from '../Shared/Icon.vue';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const showDropdown = ref(false)
const showSubmenu = ref(false)


const menu = ref([
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'dashboard',
        icon_name: 'dashboard',
        submenu: [],

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'residentes',
        icon_name: 'down',
        submenu: [
            { name: 'admin. residentes', icon: 'residentes' },
            { name: 'admin. familiares', icon: 'family' }
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'empleados',
        icon_name: 'down',
        submenu: [
            { name: 'admin. empleados', icon: 'empleados' },
            { name: 'sueldos', icon: 'sueldos' },
            { name: 'jornadas de Trabajo', icon: 'jornadas' },
            { name: 'Permisos', icon: 'permisos' }
        ],

    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'usuarios',
        icon_name: 'down',
        submenu: [
            { name: 'admin. usuarios', icon: 'usuarios' },
            { name: 'roles', icon: 'roles' },
            { name: 'acceso', icon: 'premission' }
        ],

    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'finanzas',
        icon_name: 'down',
        submenu: [
            { name: 'ingresos', icon: 'ingresos' },
            { name: 'egresos', icon: 'egresos' }
        ],

    },
])


</script>

<!-- ==================== HTML ==================== -->

<nav class="" v-if="showDropdown">
                    <ul class="">
                        <li v-for="item in menu" :key="item.id" class="pb-2">
                            <button v-if="item.submenu.length" @click="showSubmenu = !showSubmenu">
                                <Icon :name="item.icon_name" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 inline fill-slate-500" />
                                <span class="capitalize"> {{ item.name }}</span>
                            </button>
                            <Link v-else>
                                <Icon :name="item.icon_name" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 inline fill-slate-500" />
                                <span class="capitalize"> {{ item.name }}</span>
                            </Link>
                       <! -- ================ HERE IS MY SUBMENU ================ -->
                            <ul v-if="item.submenu.length && showSubmenu" class="pl-3 pt-1">
                                <li v-for="subitem in item.submenu" :key="subitem" class="pb-1">
                                    <Link class="capitalize">
                                    <Icon :name="subitem.icon" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 inline fill-slate-500" />
                                    {{ subitem.name }}
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: this is the current behavior]

Comment: click on the image to see the gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single boolean to toggle all submenus. In that case, the output would be the way shown in the picture. But you can add the booleans in the object so you can toggle differently for each item by grabbing clicked index then function call. i.e.

```
const menu = ref([
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'dashboard',
        icon_name: 'dashboard',
        submenu: [],
        toggle_submenu: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'residentes',
        icon_name: 'down',
        submenu: [
            { name: 'admin. residentes', icon: 'residentes' },
            { name: 'admin. familiares', icon: 'family' }
        ],
        toggle_submenu: false
    }], ....
```

Then,

```
var toggle_sub_menu = (index) => {
    // Loop through all object and set boolean false
   menu.forEach(function(item) {
        item.toggle_submenu = false
   });
   // toggle the selected item true
   menu[index].toggle_submenu = true;
}
```

You can call this function while clicking the toggle menu like this

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in menu" :key="item.id" class="pb-2">
<button v-if="item.submenu.length"    @click="toggle_sub_menu(index)">
```